# Azure java function does not scale to handle heavy eventhub messages?

Tags: java, function, azure

We have a heavy azure function which uses eventHub trigger binding to read data from eventHub1 , does some processing and writes to 2 other another eventhubs(eventhub2 and eventhub3 depending on transformation logic).

The eventHub1(12 partition) at one point had 200mn messages, however the function could not scale to process the entire load. In 7 days it could only process 40% of the load and eventually the rest of the messages(120mn) died in hub(without being processed) due to 7 days retention policy.

Created a support ticket with MS about the scaling issue 6 days back. Till now we have not received any valuable response from them.

Thought to present it to the azure experts out here to see if you guys have any recommendation or have faced similar issue in the past.I will be more than happy to provide further details if you need regarding the scaling issue.

```
 - Function is on consumption plan.
 - EventHub namespace is on standard tier.
 - All the hubs has 12 partitions each.
 - MS Document says function would max have n+1 instance, where n = #of partitions. 
However from live metrics I could see function running on 27 servers instances max.
```

Answer (score 0):

There a couple of things to check:

1-is it a load test where you're adding all those events at once (but in chunks) or is it being received after a few hours / days of work?

2-Are you reaching the TU units(Throughput units)?

3-Have you enabled the auto-inflate feature? (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-auto-inflate)

4-have you considered using dedicated clusters?

Comment: Thank you for your response. 1. It was a batch load. We have 12 partition and 10 TU. 3. Yes we did enable auto inflate. 4. We have not enabled using dedicated cluster. We thought we could achieve it with standard tier.

Comment: what about number 2?

Comment: didn;t see TU limits reached , when the load was processing. As we had auto-inflate on.